# Using Match in a sqlite fts5 query but need more control over ranking?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, fts5

I have a virtual table created using fts5:

```
import sqlite3
# create a db in memory
con = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
con.execute('create virtual table operators using fts5(family, operator, label, summary, tokenize=porter)')

# some sample data
samples = {'insideTOP':
              {'label':'Inside',
               'family':'TOP',
               'summary':'The Inside TOP places Input1 inside Input2.'
              },
           'inTOP':
              {'label':'In',
               'family':'TOP',
               'summary':'The In TOP is used to create a TOP input.'
              },
           'fileinSOP':
              {'label':'File In',
               'family':'SOP',
               'summary':'The File In SOP allows you to read a file'
              }
          }

# fill db with those values
for operator in samples.keys():
    opDescr = samples[operator]
    con.executescript("insert into operators (family, operator, label, summary) values ('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}');".format(opDescr['family'],operator,opDescr['label'],opDescr['summary']))
```

with following columns

```
+--------+-----------+------------+----------------------------------------------+
| family | operator  |   label    |            summary                           |
+--------+-----------+------------+----------------------------------------------+
| TOP    | insideTOP | Inside     | The Inside TOP places Input1 inside Input2.|
| TOP    | inTOP     | In         | The In TOP is used to create a TOP input.    |
| SOP    | fileinSOP | File In    | The File In SOP allows you to read a file    |
+--------+-----------+------------+----------------------------------------------+
```

an example query is:

```
# query the db
query = "select operator from operators where operators match 'operator:In*' or operators match 'label:In*' order by family, bm25(operators)"
result = con.execute(query)

for row in result:
    print(row)
```

And as a result I get

- fileinSOP
- insideTOP
- inTOP

For this particular case though, I'd actually like the 'inTOP' to appear before the 'insideTOP' as the label is a perfect match.

What would be a good technique to be able to massage these results the way I'd like them?

Thank you very much

Markus

Comment: Can you please share your DB setup so we can easier replicate your situation?

Comment: The `operator` column is checked for a match before `label`, so your "perfect match" is probably never even looked at in the query.

Comment: @Corion - I added an example script for this.

Comment: @Shawn - Thanks! I reversed the order but the result doesn't change.

Comment: If you look at what `bm25(operators)` returns for your results, you'll see the two TOP rows have the same value, so their ordering is going to be arbitrary (Probably the order they were inserted into the table). If you add label to the end of the ORDER BY list, the shorter one will sort first.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can put your order rule in the question.

If you use bm25 to order your results, you can't achieve the result you want
I suggest you that you can use your custom rank function, like below sql:

```
query = "select operator from operators where operators match 'operator:In*' or operators match 'label:In*' order by myrank(family, operators)"
```

define a custom rank function is very easy in fts5, you can follow the guide in the fts5 website.

if you also want bm25 result as a rank score, you can get the score in the rank method can calculate your final score.